# React state variable -> undefined vs false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Question is about what would be the best approach ->

For example : There is a `termsAndCondition` acceptance checkbox in a react component. If the user submits the next button on that component, there should be an error shown if user didn't selected the checkbox.

To handle this what I am doing is -> create a state variable, which is set to undefined on the component load, set to true when user selects and false if not selected and pressed the button. The condition to show the error message is when that state variable is `false`

so it's like `if(termsAccepted === false) {
    console.log("show error message");
}`

I really hate to check for false state variable here, also

I **can't** simply do `if(!termsAccepted) {
    console.log("show error message");
}`

because then it would show error message on the component load, which should not be the case

So what should be best way to handle this. There are many such situation when one has to decide between undefined and false.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, so it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. The answer will also vary depending on your overall requirements, and to a certain extent your coding style.

Comment: yeah it's a really a matter of opinion. I could suggest you to use string e.g. 'ACCEPTED', 'REJECTED', or undefined (initial state). But ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As a side note, though: In this *specific* case, what's the purpose of the indeterminate state (`undefined`)? If it's a checkbox, the user can only see two states (assuming you don't disable the checkbox): checked or unchecked.